# How to get the last applied timestamp of a secret in kube api

Tags: kubernetes, kube-apiserver

I want to get the last time a secret was modified via the kube api. I cannot seem to find a way to access this information. I had a look at events but I cannot find any for Secrets.

An example would be I create a secret called my-secret, I then update this the next day but I want to know what time it was updated and not the creation time.

Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The following command will give you the secret chronological history:

`kubectl get secret <name> --namespace <namespace> --show-managed-fields -o jsonpath='{range .metadata.managedFields[*]}{.manager}{" did "}{.operation}{" at "}{.time}{"\n"}{end}'`

Example, create a secret:
`kubectl create secret generic test --from-literal user=$(echo 'somebody' | base64)`

Run the above command:

> kubectl-create did Update at **2021-12-06T01:12:17Z**

Retrieve the created secret
`kubectl get secret test -o yaml > test.yaml`. Replace the value for "user" in the yaml with `echo 'nobody' | base64` output and re-apply `kubectl apply -f test.yaml`.

Run the above command and it reports the last update action and timestamp:

> kubectl-create did Update at **2021-12-06T01:12:17Z**
>
> kubectl-client-side-apply did Update at **2021-12-06T01:13:33Z**

Now do a replace `kubectl patch secret test --type='json' -p='[{"op" : "replace" ,"path" : "/data/user" ,"value" : "aGVsbG93b3JsZAo="}]'`

Run the above command again:

> kubectl-create did Update at **2021-12-06T01:12:17Z**
>
> kubectl-client-side-apply did Update at **2021-12-06T01:13:33Z**
>
> kubectl-patch did Update at **2021-12-06T01:21:57Z**

The command correctly reports all the changes made to the secret.

Comment: Thanks, this does not work though when using an apply. When you create a secret then update it via an apply the data is incorrect. The example below shows the creation time E.g.
`kubectl-client-side-apply did Update at 2021-12-05T20:38:19Z`

Comment: See the updated answer with example. Can you repeat the same in your environment and paste the output in your question if you don't see the same.